# F# how to prevent function with Console.Readline() from being run

Tags: f#

This question is bit weird but I am not able to find answer for it. I created a simple function

```
let answer = 
printf "give k or n"
let ret = Console.ReadLine()
if ret = "k" then true
else false
```

Now everytime I build the project and run .exe this function is being ran at first then the stuff in main. I would like to run it only when called. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `answer` as a function:

```
let answer () = 
    printf "give k or n"
    let ret = Console.ReadLine()
    ret = "k"
```

Comment: Superb! Thanks. So the reason why it is picked is just that other functions have parameters but this does not?

Comment: @Kamsiinov : In F#, functions must have at least one parameter by definition; if there are no parameters it isn't a function, but a value.